# Share cookies among spa and api rest .net core

Tags: .net, api, cookies, single-page-application, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to read cookies from the controller in the api rest saved from a SPA Middleware

I have 2 SPA projects (www.spa1.com, www.spa2.com) and one for the rest (api.spa1.com, api.spa2.com). I'm trying to read cookies from the controller in the api rest saved from a SPA Middleware

```
SPA Middleware:
```

```cs
        private void AddCookie(HttpContext context, string key, string value)
        {
            context.Response.Cookies.Append(key, value,
                new CookieOptions
                {
                    Path = "/",
                    Domain = context.Request.Host.Host,
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Secure = true,
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(3),
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
                });
        }
```

[image: API controller]

Comment: It's called cross-domain cookie sharing, if you want you can read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies. Since  a cookie is tied to it's domain you need to create cookies on the same domain.

Comment: Cookies are saved and read from applications in the same domain, for example: www.spa1.com and api.spa1.com.